# Wordpress plugin access method in UI

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, plugins, wordpress-gutenberg

How can I trigger particular method in React component of Wordpress plugin. E.g. Gutenberg?

Say, we have a wordpress plugin with React UI (e.g. Gutenberg) It has a component. 
I need somehow to access/import this component and trigger it's method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in UI of a wordpress editor I have a namespace which can be accessible with a short

`wp.`

syntax and allows to work with multiple method described in official documentation.
In my case I did need to access it like so:

`wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getBlockAttributes`

This is also described in official docs:
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core-block-editor/